# Using custom router switch in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the different between this two code?

```
const GenerateRoute = ({ route }) => {
  return <Route exact={route.exact} path={route.route} render={() => <route.component />} />;
};

return (
  <Switch location={location}>
    {MenuItem.map(item => (
      <GenerateRoute route={item} />
    ))}
  </Switch>
)
```

```
return (
  <Switch location={location}>
    {MenuItem.map(item => (
      <Route exact={item.exact} path={item.route} render={() => <item.component />} />
    ))}
  </Switch>
)
```

because the first one is not working as I expected while the second one does.

is React Router Switch not support custom Route component? or how the code supposed to be if I want to using my custom function to generate Route component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Switch>` component will need to check the children's `path` **directly**.

Thus, to have an component-wrapper-route, you will have something like:

```
const GenerateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  // inject or do something
  return (
    <Route {...rest} component={Component} />
  );
};

{ MenuItem.map((item, index) => (
    <GenerateRoute
      key={index}
      exact={item.exact}
      path={item.route} // child must have path shown
      component={item.component}
    />
  ))
}
```

Comment: this working perfectly, thank you for your help!!!!